# How to redirect home page on a specific site with WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress site and I installed Multisite. WordPress is at the root (like `example.com/`). My other sites (multisite) are like `portfolio.example.com`.

I don't want my home page to be my WordPress site. I want it to be the home page I created (with my CSS and my JS) and it is in a folder in `example.com/index`.

I tried to redirect with a `Redirect 301 /index.php https://example.com/index` and a `Redirect 301 https://example.com https://example.com/index` but it redirects all my `index.php` to `example.com/index` so even `portfolio.example.com` becomes `example.com/index` because of the WordPress structure.

How can I redirect only my home page `example.com` to `example.com/index` keeping `portfolio.example.com` to `portfolio.example.com`?

I hope this is clear... Thanks!

Here is my `.htaccess` (it's the one generated by WP + my redirection line) :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Les directives (lignes) entre « BEGIN WordPress » et « END WordPress » sont générées
# dynamiquement, et doivent être modifiées uniquement via les filtres WordPress.
# Toute modification des directives situées entre ces marqueurs sera surchargée.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]


# Redirection d’une URL vers une autre
Redirect 301 /index.php https://mysite.au/index


</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: "it is in a folder in `mysite.au/index`" - What is the actual _file_?

Comment: Oops, it's index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply redirect/rewrite `index.php` since that is the WordPress front-controller and all requests are written to it.

I would have expected you to want to internally "rewrite" the request, rather than externally "redirect" the request, and keep the user at the "homepage" URL, ie. `example.com/`, rather than expose the true location of `/index/index.html`.

You can use mod_rewrite to internally rewrite (not "redirect") direct requests (as opposed to rewritten requests) for the document root to `/index/index.html`.

Note that you should not manually edit the code between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers since WordPress itself maintains this block of code and will try to overwrite this later.

Try the following to the very top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

```
# Rewrite the "example.com" homepage to "/index/index.html"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ index/index.html [END]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

The *condition* that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that only direct requests from the user are rewritten and not internally rewritten requests by the later WordPress rewrite.

However, the above allows the user to request `/`, `/index.php` or `/index/index.html` to access your custom homepage (ie. `/index/index.html`).

You should include a "redirect" *before* this that removes `index.php` (or `index/index.html`) if requested directly. The above rewrite can then be simplified. For example, try the following instead:

```
# Redirect to remove "index.php" or "index/index.html" if requested directly
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|index/index\.html)$ / [R=301,L]

# Rewrite the homepage to "/index/index.html"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]   
RewriteRule ^$ index/index.html [END]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to check for the requested hostname, so it only rewrites `example.com` and not `portfolio.example.com`.

Comment: Okkk thank you! To be honest I don't understand everything, but I have the idea and of course it's working :), thanks a lot!